# Sagemaker Studio lab notebook environment

Tags: amazon-web-services

The Amazon Sagemaker Studio lab notebook environment only shows me the option of a default Python kernel, and installing ipykernel still does not give me the option of selecting the correct conda environment.

I have restarted the jupyterlab but still in the notebook the environment that is activated is default and not studiolab.

Does anyone know how do we start the notebooks in studio lab so that they run in the correct conda environment?

I am expecting that I should be able to run the notebook in the studiolab conda environment